# nestjs and nodemailer no send email on production?

Tags: nestjs, nodemailer

nest and nodemailer.
I have an error that when sending an email in development mode it works very well but when compiling for production it gives me the following error:

2023-08-02 06:00:31 error al enviar Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:465

The ports 465 are open, I have tried it in ubuntu server in production mode with the firewall turned off and however it gives me the error. I am using an email from my service provider that works in nestjs development mode

I have read in the forums but I do not see a solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
MailerModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
    transport: {
      host: config.get('EMAIL_HOST'),
      port: Number(process.env.EMAIL_PORT),
      secure: true,
      debug: true, // Habilitar logs de depuración
      logger: true,
      secureConnection: false, // TLS requires secureConnection to be false
      ignoreTLS: true,
      auth: {
        user: config.get('EMAIL_USER'),
        pass: config.get('EMAIL_PASSWORD'),
      },
      tls: {
        // must provide server name, otherwise TLS certificate check will fail
        servername: "c1481844.ferozo.com",
        rejectUnauthorized: true
      }
      
    },
    defaults: {
      from: 'dickson@darse.do'
    },
    template: {
      dir: join(__dirname, 'mails'),
      adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
      options: {
        strict: true
      }
    }
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService]
}),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).